# How can I style flowbite react tabs?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, flowbite

I am using Tabs from flowbite, the tailwind component library. But there is no way to customize the design colors of the tabs. Is any have used it?

This is the output

[image: 1]

```
import { Tabs } from "flowbite-react";     

export default function CoursesTab() {
  return (
    <>
      <Tabs.Group aria-label="Tabs with underline" style="underline" className="justify-between">
        {categories.map((category, index) => {
          return (
            <Tabs.Item className="Chinmoy" key={index} title={category.name}>
              {category.name} content
            </Tabs.Item>
          );
        })}
      </Tabs.Group>
    </>
  );
}
```

How to customize the tabs color and border color

Answer (score 0):

One of the solutions can be adding a `theme` to the component.
For example,

```
// Refer the object from https://www.flowbite-react.com/docs/components/tabs

const customTabTheme: FlowbiteTabTheme = {
  "base": "flex flex-col gap-2",
  ...
}

export default function CoursesTab() {
  return (
    <>
      <Tabs.Group 
        aria-label="Tabs with underline" 
        style="underline" 
        className="justify-between"
        theme={customTabTheme}   // <-- Add theme like this
      >
        {categories.map((category, index) => {
          return (
            <Tabs.Item className="Chinmoy" key={index} title={category.name}>
              {category.name} content
            </Tabs.Item>
          );
        })}
      </Tabs.Group>
    </>
  );
}
```

You may see the tab colors and boders in the theme object.